# How to reload WordPress admin post/page body with jQuery after initial load?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I would like to reload the post-body div when you Add New page. I'm changing the 'Page Attributes' parent selection and then based on that I'd like to load ACF group content.

I tried several different ways and this is what somewhat works out, but the action doesn't fully complete what I need it to do.

Want I'm looking for is the WP Editor to hide and the ACF group component to show up with all the fields (screenshot below).

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'admin_inline_js' );
function admin_inline_js() {
    print '<script type="text/javascript">$("#post-body").load(location.href + " #post-body>*");</script>';
}
```

[image]

Comment: do you want to hide wp-editor and want to display acf field content?

Comment: Yes, but I want to do it after initial page load, because I can't find a way to pass the Parent to the Add New page before load, do you know a way? Now I guess this is more ACF question, because all the data is loaded &I need is to find how ACF does the show/hide.